# How to install an old version of Open Office?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

I am trying to reinstall Antidote (a spell checker good with French grammar). It has to be integrated with (for example) Open Office.

I have the install CD but it can only integrate with Open Office up to version 3.x. An update to a newer Antidote costs 50 euros. So I decided I would install Open Office 3.4.1 and use it to spellcheck with Antidote.

I found ooobasis3.4-sdk_3.4.1-1_amd64.deb here :
http://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/ooo/files/stable/3.4.1/

But ooobasis3.4-sdk depends on ooobasis3.4-core01, and I'm stuck. Where is ooobasis3.4-core01? And how to I avoid having to download and to uncompress the dependencies one by one? I think I need to add something to my sources.list but what?

Any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if anyone is maintaining old Libreoffice versions to continue working on newer distributions of Linux. As such, if old installation files do not work on your current Ubuntu version, I doubt you will find updated deb files of that old version that do.

Your alternative then may be to compile old source code of Libreoffice yourself. But that is merely theory, because compiling LO is not a trivial task, and you probably would need to adapt old source code to work with the newer code base of your system.

Somewhat more realistic, if you really want that old spelling software to work, could be to install an older version of linux in a virtual machine. It is adviced then to keep that old linux version disconnected from the internet. Old versions are not anymore maintained and may expose you to a range of vulnerabilities.

Integration of your Antidote software with LO thus will not quite practical. However, the software perhaps can be used independently, provided you can install it on your current Ubuntu. That would be the only practical solution to continue using that software.

You still can pay 50 euro, of course, to continue using this proprietary software with current versions of LO.